# Magento 2: magento layout not pick by magento

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.0

I found this error in system.log file and my layout is not loading in frontend.

```
main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'before.body.end'. [] []
```

Comment: problem solved. by adding layout="1column" in mymodule_index_index.xml file in page node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem Solved :

By just adding lines in below file .
in `mymodule_index_index.xml`  files `page` node I  Add `layout=1column` and the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm getting this error while layout="1column" already existing.

Comment: @Nitesh please provide full code and and ask new question for that and put this question link as a refrence

Answer (score 4):

In XML located at view/frontend/layout/servicecontractclient_index_index.xml

Instead of

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Change it to

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

The difference is adding `layout="1column"`.
Now there is another error but at least the Block class and the template are correctly being called.